# Error 'Service' object has no attribute 'process' while using python beautiful soup extraction with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am using this code for scrapping some data from the link *https://website.grader.com/results/www.dubizzle.com*. Because the actual script with the tags I want to extract loads after a 15 seconds of load, someone recommended me selenuim to introduce a delay in the code. Hence I use this code

The code is as below

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta
import MySQLdb
import re
import pdb
import sys
import string

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://website.grader.com/results/dubizzle.com')
time.sleep(25)
html = driver.page_source
soup  = BeautifulSoup(html)

# print soup

Sizeofweb=""
try:

    Sizeofweb= soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': ".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0"}).text
    print Sizeofweb.get_text().encode("utf-8")

except StandardError as e:
    converted_date="Error was {0}".format(e)
    print converted_date
```

The part of the html which I am extracting is as below

Snap: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dwbaiyizwa36m6/5.PNG?dl=0

```html
<div class="result-value" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1">
 <span data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.0">1.1</span>
 <span class="result-value-unit" data-reactid=".0.0.3.0.0.3.$0.1.1.1">MB</span>
</div>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ahmed.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f65a1ccbe10>> ignored
```

Comment: Hi _info_ ; I have edited your question to improve the readability a bit, for example I fixed a few spelling mistakes. Remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear and useful as possible; that helps you get an answer, and helps anybody else struggling with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a current FireFox webdriver installed or in your path, the code is running into error before even initiating the browser at

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

To fix this, you will need to install (or reinstall) the firefox driver and add it to your path.

Comment: im using the host vps. How to add it plz?

Comment: :) can anyone answer?

Comment: (Assuming you have Selenium all set up) [Download the webdriver exec](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) Unzip and add file location to path. 'export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver'

Comment: [See here for more support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

Comment: I am weak in commads to zip and unzip, can you modify your answer with the commands plz?